# NoMethodError when rendering a form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

routes.rb:

```
resources :shops
```

shop_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @shop=Shop.new
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@shop) do |f| %>
....
<% end %>
```

error:
undefined method `shops_path' for:

```
<%= form_for(@shop) do |f| %>
```

The problem is that I already specify the shop resources in the routes file.
Why still get such kind of error?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: `shop_controller` should be `shops_controller`

Comment: can you add output of `rake routes` to your question?

Comment: new_shop GET    /shops/new(.:format)                                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"shops"}, here the info after "rake routes"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ShopsController` not `ShopController` due to Rails naming convention.

Comment: sorry, actually it is "shops_controller.rb". I missed the "s" when I was posting this question.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for all your inputs. Once I solve the problem, I  will post the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these lines in your `rake routes` output:

```
   shops GET    /shops(.:format   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"shops"}
         POST   /shops(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"shops"}
```

OR

```
   shops POST   /shops(.:format)   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"shops"}
```

If they aren't present, look carefully at your `routes.rb` for possible `with_options`, `scope` or any other scoping that can affect your `resources :shops` in such a way that it doesn't generate default url helpers.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I got all rake routes outputs in the answer. And I don't have anything about scoping in the routes.rb. But the exception still happens. Weird problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird indeed. If you're still in search for answer, I'd suggest to edit your question and add full backtrace from your exception.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for all your inputs. Once I solve the problem, I  will post the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: It's working if I set the version of rails to 3.1.3. But in Rails 3.2, the problem happens again.

Answer (score 0):

since u havent specified the method in the form tag, i guess it is going as a GET request. Try adding the method to ur form

```
<%= form_for(@shop), :method => :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for all your inputs. Once I solve the problem, I  will post the solution. Thanks again.